# SQL - Group dependant upon type

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've updated the question below as there's a little more complexity to it ...

A question relating to SQL grouping based on type?

I'd like to be able to list the max value for type-A (based on date - per CustID) whilst at the same time listing ALL values for type-b

From this :

```
Date          Ref   Type  CustID
2019-03-04    123   A     1
2019-03-05    124   A     1
2019-03-06    125   B     3
2019-03-07    126   B     4
2019-03-08    127   B     5
2019-03-06    128   A     2
2019-03-07    129   A     2
2019-03-08    130   A     2
```

To this :

```
Date          Ref   Type CustID
2019-03-05    124   A    1
2019-03-06    125   B    3
2019-03-07    126   B    4 
2019-03-08    127   B    5
2019-03-08    130   A    2
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The majority of the comments below do very much the same thing - so thank you to everyone ... I've updated the original question as there's a little more complexity - I'd like to be able to list the max value for type-A (based on date - per CustID) whilst at the same time listing ALL values for type-b

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
with a as (
      select top (1) t.*
      from t
      where type = 'A'
      order by ref desc
     )
select a.*
from a
union all
select t.*
from t
where type = 'B';
```

Or without `union all`:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by (case when type = 'B' then 1
               else row_number() over (partition by type order by ref desc
          end);
```

Answer (score 0):

use union all

```
select date,ref,type from table where type='B'
union all
select date,ref,type from table where type='A' 
and date = (select max(date) from table where type='A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  using `union all`

```
select top 1 date,ref, type from tablename
where Type='A' order by date desc
union all
select date,ref, type from tablename
where type='B'
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query gives you type `A`  records with latest date combined with `B` records

```
  Select * from
   ( SELECT  Date, Ref, Type 
     FROM TABLE
    WHERE TYPE='A' GROUP BY TYPE
    HAVING DATE =MAX(DATE)
     UNION
    SELECT  Date, Ref, Type FROM TABLE
     WHERE TYPE='B'
          )
```